# App crashes on iPhone 6, iOS 12.5 while testing in device using Xcode 13.2

Tags: swift, iphone, ios13.2

Console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6A606806-B567-4237-9B63-561126BF5E96/Appname.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib (which was built for iOS 13.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6A606806-B567-4237-9B63-561126BF5E96/Appname.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib
```

the app is running smoothly in the simulator with iOS 12.4

I tried making `libswift_Concurrency.dbt` optional. It did not stop the app from crashing.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in Xcode 13.3 . Please update Xcode

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue today, the issue was weird because everything just worked well before today. After some checks, I found that my system automatically updated Xcode from 13.1 to 13.2 last night. The [Xcode 13.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2-release-notes) shows that Xcode 13.2 has a compiler issue about `libswift_Concurrency.dylib` library, and it provides a `Workaround`  method to resolve, but I found out the method doesn't work for me after I tried it.

I still don't know the reason which causes this issue, but I did make my project run on my iphone6 again by **rollback Xcode to the version of 13.1** .

If your issue also caused by the update of Xcode, you can try this method.  [Download here: Xcode13.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2013.1)

Comment: But see my other answer. There are known bugs in the "automatic" version you got from the App Store. The manual version of 13.2 is way better.

Comment: Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Yes, In Xcode 13.1 there is no crash. Thank you

Comment: I'm seeing crashes on my Production app on iPhone 6 iOS version 12.5.5. Any chance that's connected?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 12-12.5: use Xcode 13.1 and update your *Pods* (i.e. last versions for Realm) (bitcode is enabled by default). Xcode 13.2.1 still crashes on device with iOS 12 but runs fine on simulator.

Comment: As mentioned above, 12.5.5 still crashes on Xcode 13.2.1. I've uploaded a version with Xcode 13.1 and now the app is not crashing in 12.5.5

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed Xcode 13.2 from the App Store. Don't. There are bugs in that version. Go to `developer.Apple.com` and download Xcode directly from there.

Comment: You can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 13.2.1 *claims* it resolves this issue (see the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2_1-release-notes)) - in fact the issue presists.

Comment: It is still crashing on real device . iphone 6s - iOS 12.5.5

Comment: DId you manage to solve this? @AbdullahMohammadDaihan

Comment: Indeed even for me it still crashes. I was going by the release notes which explicitly state that this was fixed.

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta No man . I am unable to resolve this

Comment: This issue has been resolved in Xcode 13.3 . Please update Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Douglas Gregor [confirmed that Xcode 13.3 beta 1](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-concurrency-back-deploy-issue/53917/29) fixes the issue.

Personally, I'll use Xcode 13.1 and then use Xcode 13.3 when the final release comes out.